# Django Test - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I got errors when running tests

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'interfacegraph' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['interfacegraph/(?P<device>[A-Z0-9.]{12,15})/(?P<interface>\\d+)/(?P<graph>\\d+)/graph/']
```

Here is the urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'interfacegraph/(?P<device>[A-Z0-9.]{12,15})/(?P<interface>\d+)/(?P<graph>\d+)/graph',
        InterfaceGraphViewSet.as_view({'get': 'graph'}), name='interfacegraph'),
 ]
```

And heres the line of code in tests where the test throws errors

```
    response = self.client.get(
        reverse('interfacegraph'), {'device': 'device', 'interface': 'interface', 'graph': 'traffic'},
        content_type='application/json')
```

The viewset is extending generics viewset

```
  class InterfaceGraphViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

Any idea how to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually pass arguments to reverse function. Use it that way:

```
reverse('interfacegraph', kwargs={'device': 'device', 'interface': 'interface', 'graph': 'traffic'})
```

Also another problem is here:

```
(?P<device>[A-Z0-9.]{12,15})
```

You are passing `'device'`, that does not fit that regex. It checks uppercase letters and digits, so in given string you have exactly `0` occurencies.
Learn about [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp). You can also not use it at all, like:

```
path('interfacegraph/<str:device>/<int:interface>/<int:graph>/graph', ...)
```